# How do I create an object such as a wall in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am programming a game in JavaScript, the game involves player one controlling an image of a head around the screen by using the arrows on the keyboard. The aim is to get as much burgers shown on the screen. Once you get it, it will randomly appear somewhere else on the screen. My first problem is how do i create an obstacle such as a wall in JavaScript? my second problem is how do i create a rule that result's in game over if the obstacle is touched?

Comment: The gist of it is checking x,y positions, but you should show the code you have right now so we can help you figure out what you need

Comment: var Manager = {
 speed: 300 // movement in pixels per second
};
var trophy = {};
var trophiesCaught = 0;

// Handle keyboard controls
var keysDown = {};

addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
 keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);

addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
 delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
}, false);

Comment: var reset = function () {
 Manager.x = canvas.width / 2;
 Manager.y = canvas.height / 2;

 // Throw the trophy somewhere on the screen randomly
 trophy.x = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 64));
 trophy.y = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 64));
};

Comment: @Keatinge thats some of the coding

Comment: @Keatinge theres the coding

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to solve by using box2D, and I use the framework which integrates box2D.

this is the example link I did 2 mins ago:[**game link**](http://studio.holaverse.com/apprun.html?mode=preview&user_id=73&game_key=f249b656271b491d919ddc81125aab57&company_id=7)

if you don't know how to use it,my facebook messenger is **Alan Nie**

Comment: what function do you want?I redo the Demo:[game link](http://studio.holaverse.com/apprun.html?mode=preview&user_id=73&game_key=f249b656271b491d919ddc81125aab57&company_id=7)

Comment: Add this code on function keydown

var win = this.win
var pos = win.circle_2.getPosition()
console.log(pos + "----")
switch (code) {
    case 37:
        win.circle_2.setPosition(pos.x - 10,pos.y)
        break;
    case 38:
        win.circle_2.setPosition(pos.x,pos.y - 10)
        break;
    case 39:
        win.circle_2.setPosition(pos.x + 10,pos.y)
        break;
    case 40:
        win.circle_2.setPosition(pos.x,pos.y + 10)
        break;    
    default:
        // code
}